# How do I calculate the difference between the same field in two different rows in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that has ID, Name, & Value in it. For each ID there are multiple names. Example:

```
| ROW | ContactID | Name       | Value                     |
| --- | --------- | ---------- | ------------------------- |
| 1   | 1111      | camp_Start | 2023-03-08 06:14:07:20200 |
| 2   | 1111      | camp_End   | 2023-03-08 06:14:07:36000 |
| 3   | 1111      | Tkt_Start  | 2023-03-08 06:14:06:54800 |
| 4   | 1111      | Tkt_End    | 2023-03-08 06:14:07:04500 |
| 5   | 2222      | camp_Start | 2023-03-08 06:14:44:24900 |
| 6   | 2222      | camp_End   | 2023-03-08 06:14:44:70500 |
```

I need to determine the duration in milliseconds between the Value of Camp_Start and Camp_End as well as Tkt_Start and Tkt_End for each ID.

Is there an easy way to do this in Snowflake?

I tried this below but getting an ambiguous error "SQL compilation error: ambiguous column name 'NAME'":

```
SELECT a.ContactID, b.Name, (a.value - b.value) Duration
FROM "PROD"."MART"."KINETIC_NICE_COMPLETED_CONTACTS_CUSTOM_DATA" a
JOIN "PROD"."MART"."KINETIC_NICE_COMPLETED_CONTACTS_CUSTOM_DATA" b
ON a.ContactID = b.contactid AND a.name = b.name
Where ( name LIKE 'gv_%end' OR name LIKE 'gv_%start' )
AND contactID = '460576582924'
AND  DF_CREATE_DT >= '03/08/2023'
AND  DF_CREATE_DT < '03/09/2023';
```

I need to find the time difference between camp_start and camp_end labeled as camp. Same for Tkt_start & Tkt_end labeled as Tkt for each ContactID

I would like to see something like the below:

```
| ContactID   | Name    | Value  |
| ----------- | ------- | ------ |
| 1111        | Camp    | .158   |
| 1111        | Tkt     | .0497  |
| 2222        | Camp    | .456   |
```

Comment: Would each `ContactID` always have only one camp or ticket start/end pair?

Comment: yes. Each ContactID will have only one start & stop of each of the names

Comment: You should also include the output you expect based on this input.

Comment: Hi - what ambiguous error are you getting? Also, if you are supplying additional information (such as the error message or the expected output) please update your question so all the information is in one place; don’t provide information in comments

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added the full error in the question above along with the example of desired output.